# Return filename when using "GetOneFile" Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I want to be able to hit a button which will open another Excel file, then upon selecting the file to open I want the filename to be able to be returned to a cell in the original Excel file. Can anyone help?

Comment: Sub OpenOneFile()
Dim fn As Variant
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    If TypeName(fn) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    ' the user didn't select a file
    If Filename <> False Then
    
Dim sFileName As String

    sFileName = Application.OpenOneFile

End If

    Debug.Print "Selected file: " & fn
    Workbooks.Open fn
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the result **before** opening the second file:

```
Sub StoreTheResultFirst()
    Dim FileSpec As String, NameOnly As String

    FileSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Range("A1").Value = FileSpec

    ary = Split(FileSpec, "\")
    NameOnly = ary(UBound(ary))
    Range("A2").Value = NameOnly

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileSpec
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the necessary error trap:

```
Sub StoreTheResultFirst2()
    Dim FileSpec As String, NameOnly As String

    FileSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If FileSpec = "False" Then
        MsgBox "User Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Range("A1").Value = FileSpec

    ary = Split(FileSpec, "\")
    NameOnly = ary(UBound(ary))
    Range("A2").Value = NameOnly

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileSpec
End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I have so far. It is the filename of the second file I am opening that I want to store into the first file where I have the Macro.

Comment: Sub OpenOneFile()
Dim fn As Variant
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsx", _
        1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    If TypeName(fn) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    ' the user didn't select a file
    If Filename <> False Then
    
Dim sFileName As String

    sFileName = Application.OpenOneFile

End If

    Debug.Print "Selected file: " & fn
    Workbooks.Open fn
End Sub

Comment: Ok, I have tried your suggestion, It works however I need some error processing in case the user selects Cancel. At present it comes back with a VB error saying cannot find false.xlsx. Can you help?